# Haemoglobin literature spectra does not match

Tags: spectroscopy, spectrophotometry

I am studying haemoglobin absorption spectra in its oxygenated and deoxygenated state and I compiled values from different sources including:

- A PhD thesis by van Assendelft [1], using extinction coefficients in (mmol/L)-1/cm
- A book compiling almost one century of research on the topic by the same laboratory that helped standardizing the haemoglobin cyanide standard [2]. Extinction coefficients in the same unit as [1], numerical values are very close.
- Coefficients compiled by Scott Prahl[3]. The unit is the same but there is a factor 3.7 up to 4.0 between his data and that of Assendelft and Zijlstra.
- Coefficients measured by Kolyva[4].

All the published coefficients are defined as base 10 extinction coefficient. That is if *I*
is the light intensity, they are expressed in Beer-Lambert law as:

$I = I_0 \cdot 10^{-c\cdot \varepsilon \cdot l}$

Where $l$ is the light path length (cm), $c$ the concentration in absorbing compound (mol/L) and $\varepsilon$ the molar extinction coefficient (L/mol/cm).

**How comes there is a 3.7-4.0 factor between Prahl and Kolyva data on the one hand and Assendelft and Zijlstra on the other hand?**

At first I thought of some $log(10)\approx2.3$ difference, as if some of the author forgot to precise that they used base $e$ extinction coefficient at some point but it does not fit. If anyone has an idea on the topic, the help would be most appreciated.

[image: Valid XHTML]

---

**Further information**

The cyanmethaemoglobin method is often used for the determination of the haemoglobin concentration of a solution. In particular, its absorbance at **540nm** is known to be 11.00L/mmol/cm[5] which is in agreement with Assendelft and Zijlstra published data.

#### References

1. O.W. Assendelft, *Spectrophotometry of Haemoglobin Derivatives*, **1970**. ISBN: 902320560X.
2. W.G. Zijlstra, A. Buursma and O.W. van Assendelft, *Visible and Near Infrared Absorption Spectra of Human and Animal Haemoglobin*, **2000**. ISBN: 9067643173.
3. Scott Prahl, *Optical Absorption of Hemoglobin*, **1999**, https://omlc.org/spectra/hemoglobin/
4. C. Kolyva, *Systematic investigation of changes in oxidized cerebral cytochrome c oxidase concentration during frontal lobe activation in healthy adults*, **2012**. DOI: [10.1364/BOE.3.002550](https://dx.doi.org/10.1364%2FBOE.3.002550). Coefficients are in [**MEDIA 1**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3469997/bin/boe-3-10-2550-s001.PDF).
5. F. Meng, *Determination of extinction coefficients of human hemoglobin in various redox states*, **2017**. DOI: [10.1016/j.ab.2017.01.002](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016%2Fj.ab.2017.01.002). Table 1.

Comment: In Scott Prahl's article, he discusses that some authors consider equivalents and some use molar values and that this would create a 4x difference in the values. Have you factored this in?

Comment: @Tyberius Thanks a lot, I had read it long ago and forgotten it by the time I came to look at those spectra once again. Thank you for the fresh look you had on the issue! I answered the question with your remark :)

(Kind of weirdly, I had the reflex to open the different books and articles I had found here and there because they were "publications" but had not that of rereading Prahl's article which I classified unconsciously as a "blog post", thus less likely to contain valuable information. My bad.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by Scott Prahl :

> One of the most confusing things about looking at hemoglobin (Hb)
>   spectra is that the values are typically tabulated in equivalents. The
>   term equivalent is used to indicate the amount of hemoglobin which
>   contains 1 gm atom of Fe and combines with 1 gm molecule of O2 or CO.
>   One equivalent of hemoglobin is assumed to be 64,500/4 or 16,125 gm. A
>   concentration of 10$^{-6}$ equivalent is 16.125mg of hemoglobin per cc.

It seems that Assendelft and Zijlstra used the **equivalent** quantification of haemoglobin, meaning that all their extinction coefficients should be multiplied by 4. This leads to the following figure:

[image: Literature-extracted haemoglobin absorption spectra]

*Sorry for not having read again Scott Prahl's description before posting. I read it several months ago, as I was gathering data from different source and forgotten it since...*